# Step signal for ADC testing

Tags: signal-analysis, analog-to-digital

IEEE std1241-2010 specification part 4.2.3. step signal setup part shows like this design

[image]

What should the test setup described in section numbered be like? Is it enough to give one pulse and read it with ADC?

"Precision pulses and step signals can be used to measure both time domain parameters
(such as impulse response, transition duration, overshoot, and settling time) and frequency domain parameters (such as frequency response amplitude and phase, bandwidth, and gain flatness)."

What kind of relationship should I establish between the parameters given above and the step or pulse signal?

Please explain using block diagram and if possible picture or images.